# UITable won't refresh even with reload called on main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, reloaddata

I have a main view controller(`SecondViewController`) with a UITable and a navigation controller. When a navigation bar button is pressed, a menu drops down from the navigation bar on top of the table. This menu is created by adding a view controller as a subview like so:

```
//SecondViewController.m
self = sortMenu.secondVC;
[self addChildViewController:sortMenu];
[self.view addSubview:sortMenu.view];
[sortMenu didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

`sortMenu` contains a button that changes the order the cells are displayed in by calling a class method of the main view controller.

```
//SortMenuViewController.m
- (IBAction)sortButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [_secondVC sortButtonPressed:[sender tag]];

}
```

In `sortButtonPressed`, it calls a method to make a fetch request with updated sort filter value.

```
//SecondViewController.m
-(void)sortButtonPressed:(NSInteger)sortDescriptor{
    _sortDescriptor = sortDescriptor;
    currentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataset & %d > 0", 4];
    [self fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex];
}
```

The fetch request is performed and returns the data in a new order.

```
//SecondViewController.m
- (IBAction)fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex
{
    NSString* sectionNameKeyPath = nil;
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = nil;
    NSSortDescriptor *scientificNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"scientificName" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *commonNameFirstDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"commonNameFirst" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *commonNameLastDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                                  initWithKey:@"commonNameLast"
                                                  ascending:YES
                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

    if (_sortDescriptor == kSortByCommonNameFirst )
    {
        sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:commonNameFirstDescriptor, commonNameLastDescriptor, scientificNameDescriptor, nil];
        sectionNameKeyPath = @"commonNameFirst";
    }
    else if (_sortDescriptor == kSortByCommonNameLast )
    {
        sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:commonNameLastDescriptor, commonNameFirstDescriptor, scientificNameDescriptor, nil];
        sectionNameKeyPath = @"commonNameLast";
    }
    else if (_sortDescriptor == kSortByScientificName )
    {
        sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:scientificNameDescriptor, commonNameFirstDescriptor, commonNameLastDescriptor, nil];
        sectionNameKeyPath = @"scientificName";
    }

    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"current predicate: %@", currentPredicate);

    [[self fetchedResultsControllerWithsectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath sortDescriptors:sortDescriptors predicate:currentPredicate] performFetch:&error];


    [scientificNameDescriptor release];
    [commonNameLastDescriptor release];
    [commonNameFirstDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSUInteger sectionsCt = [[speciesFetchedResultsController sections] count];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=1; i < sectionsCt; i++){
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[speciesFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:i];
        NSUInteger numOfObj = [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
        NSLog(@" in section %d number of objects is  %lu ", i, (unsigned long)numOfObj);
        sum  = sum + numOfObj;
    }


    [_table performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)
                                     withObject:nil
                                  waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

When I call `fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex` from the main view controller (before dropping down the sort menu), it works correctly. However, when called from `sortMenu`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are not called. I have tried to call `reloadData` on the main thread with `performSelectorOnMainThread` and also dispatching it to the main queue, but neither works.

I originally created a sort menu by adding a pickerview to the main view controller on pressing the navigation bar button, and my table reloaded correctly. Since creating a separate view controller for the menu (to have greater design control), it doesn't work.

Comment: `[_secondVC sortButtonPressed:[sender tag]];` ... How are you setting `_secondVC`?

Comment: @DonMag updated post - thank you!

Comment: `self = sortMenu.secondVC;`???? So you have instantiated your `sortMenu` view controller, then in some other view controller you assign `self` to the value of `secondVC` ***in*** `sortMenu`? And then you add `sortMenu` as a child view controller of self, which is secondVC in sortMenu, which is added to self, etc... That doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: I instantiate sortMenu and assign self as secondVC property all in the same (main) view controller

Comment: I agree with @DonMag, assigning to `self` makes no sense.  Your description of the problem sounds like you have two instances of your view controller.  One that is being displayed and one that your menu is talking to.  Did you perhaps mean to say `sortMenu.secondVC = self;`?

Comment: I thought that by assigning self, I was making sure that the menu is talking to the instance of my view controller that it being displayed. As this is wrong, what is the correct way to go about doing this? Thank you

Comment: @Paulw11 sortMenu.secondVC = self; is exactly what I meant. Thank you

Comment: Assigning `self` to a property in your chid view controller is a bad approach. You want to use the Delegate pattern. Create a Delegate; have your VC that contains your table view conform to that Delegate; instantiate `sortMenu` and assign `self` to its Delegate property; when a "menu item" is selected in `sortMenu`, use that Delegate property to "call back" to your main VC.

Comment: Actually, you can even access to parent by self.parentViewController and cast it to SecondViewController without any delegating.

Comment: @kirander so in `SortMenuViewController.m` I can simply do `_secondVC = (SecondViewController *)self.parentViewController;` ?

Comment: @Matt Yes, because "menuVC" was added as a child. But do not save it in a variable, just access when needed.

Comment: Where is the data source to ur table viez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using delegation.

```
//  SortMenuViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol SortMenuViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)sortButtonPressed:(NSInteger)sortDescriptor;
-(void)viewButtonPressed:(NSInteger)viewDescriptor;
@end

@interface SortMenuViewController : UIViewController{

}

//SortMenuViewController.m
- (IBAction)changeSort:(id)sender {

    [_delegate sortButtonPressed:[sender tag]];

}

//SecondViewController.h
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, SortMenuViewControllerDelegate>{

}
-(void)sortButtonPressed:(NSInteger)sortDescriptor{
    _sortDescriptor = sortDescriptor;
    currentPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dataset & %d > 0", dataset];
    [self fetchResultsUsingSegmentedControlIndex];
}
```